# calling functions in console.log not outputting anything in firefox console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

I'm still new to programming in general and need some help!
Here's my code block under the script tag in my html file, trying to make a simple rock, paper, scissors game work.
My problem is that nothing is appearing in my firefox console at all...
The only error message shown is this: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```js
var computerSelection = computerPlay();
var playerSelection = 'Rock';
var rpsList = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
var rpsLength = rpsList.length;

function randomChoice(rpsLength) {
  return rpsList[Math.floor((Math.random() * rpsLength)];
}

function computerPlay() {
  switch (randomChoice(rpsLength)) {
    case 'Rock':
      return "Rock";
    case 'Paper':
      return "Paper";
    case 'Scissors':
      return "Scissors";
  }
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    return 'Tie!';
  } else if (computerSelection == 'Paper' && playerSelection) {
    return 'Computer Wins! Paper covers Rock';
  } else if (computerSelection == 'Scissors' && playerSelection) {
    return 'You Win! Rock smashes Scissors!';
  } else {
    return 'Invalid option!';
  }
}

console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Tidying the code shows the error was a surplus bracket in `Math.floor((Math.random() * rpsLength)`
2. You need to have the array defined BEFORE calling the function so in your code, move `var computerSelection = computerPlay();` to before the console.log
3. No need for a switch that returns the same as it is called with
4. If playerSelection is always Rock, then no need for `&& playerSelection`
5. no need to pass a global var

```js
var playerSelection = 'Rock';
var rpsList = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
var rpsLength = rpsList.length;

function randomChoice() {
  return rpsList[Math.floor(Math.random() * rpsLength)];
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    return 'Tie!';
  } else if (computerSelection == 'Paper' && playerSelection) {
    return 'Computer Wins! Paper covers Rock';
  } else if (computerSelection == 'Scissors' && playerSelection) {
    return 'You Win! Rock smashes Scissors!';
  } else {
    return 'Invalid option!';
  }
}
console.log(playRound(playerSelection,  randomChoice()));
```